# show a part of a website with iframe tag

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

can someone give me an example how to view only a part of a website?

I would like to show a part of a website with iframe tag (using an id or class name or ?).

how can I do?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

you couldn't control an external page.Thus you’ve to scroll the IFRAME content to the desired position. This of course is impossible. even though there are some java script methods, but all are not really good. because scrolling occurs only when page is load.

the only one solution is You can wrap the IFRAME into a div and scroll the DIV content using absolute TOP and LEFT CSS properties.

see the example

**html**

```
<div id="frame-wrapper">
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" id="my-iframe" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
```

**css**

```
#frame-wrapper
{
    width    : 400px;
    height   : 220px;
    overflow : hidden;
    position : relative;
}

#my-iframe
{
    position : absolute;
    top      : -100px;
    left     : -100px;
    width    : 400px;
    height   : 220px;
}
```

see the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/iamshajeer/8dhLkwha/)